# installing ant on mac

Tags: java, android, ant

I have developed push notification in android application using gcm.here i have to set the GCM for server side.

**Generate the server's WAR file by running ant war:**

```
$ ant war

Buildfile:build.xml

init:
     [mkdir] Created dir: build/classes
     [mkdir] Created dir: dist

compile:
     [javac] Compiling 6 source files to build/classes

war:
     [war] Building war: dist/gcm-demo.war

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 0 seconds
```

Here i have to write on my terminal **$ ant war** means the below error is dipslayed.why this error is came here.how can i resolve this.please help me.

The error is:

**Buildfile: build.xml does not exist! Build failed**

Comment: there is a file called build.xml in the root of your android project ?

Comment: so where is the build.xml file? If it's not in the directory where you're executing the command, then you need to tell Ant where to find it

Comment: the build.xml file is in my ant folder

Comment: When you execute `ant war`, it's actually `ant -buildfile build.xml war`. So please go to the directory that has your build.xml and run ant again.

Comment: how is creating war file.where i can find gcm-demo.war file